# Does iPad 2 3G's GPS work without SIM card inserted?

Tags: ipad, gps, sim

I own an iPad 2 with 3G but I've not inserted SIM card and I'm not planning to unless it's really necessary to get GPS working.

I was wondering if iPad 2 3G can navigate without SIM card (thru Navigon for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for products that have off-line maps (Navigon and Tom-Tom for example) you don't need a connection.

Some add-on services (e.g., Tom-Tom traffic) will need a connection.

Comment: Great to hear. Would having a WIFI connection thru my iPhone enhance positioning?

Comment: Don't think so, you can use GSM to enhance positioning but the information is not re-delivered using personal hotspot. I don't have experience with iPad and Navigation but using an iPhone 3GS and an iPhone 4 I didn't have problems.